# Split two concatenated strings at google spreadsheet - FirstnameSurname

Tags: split, google-sheets

I want to split two combined strings. First characters are upper char like FirstnameSurname.

I tried SPLIT function, but i couldn't.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the not most elegant solution, but if one can assume that there are only two uppercase characters in the string, I was able to split FirstnameSurname this way (The string was in A4 cell):

`B4=RegExExtract(A4, "[\p{Lu}][\p{Ll}]+")`

`B5=RIGHT(A4, LEN(A4) - LEN(B4))`

Edited to support Unicode for non-English characters, like explained in [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html). (Turns out Google Spreadsheet doesn't support full Unicode property names, like `\p{Uppercase_Letter}`)

Comment: Thank you, but how about non-English letters? This solution ok, but there is a problem with non-English letters.